# Deploying React App from Codesandbox to Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages

I followed this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NapRkCazks) to deploy my react app to github pages. I made my react app in codesandbox and exported my sandbox to my [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/andair). I downloaded node.js, npm, and git.

My folder structure:
Users > test > package-lock.json + andair-master > (inside andair-master) node_modules + build > (inside build) public + src + package.json

I downloaded my github project "andair-master" and copied and pasted its contents into an empty folder "test".

I opened Git Bash and changed directories until I was in "andair-master". I did "git init" then "git remote add origin https://github.com/develijahlee/andair.git" then I tried "npm run deploy". I realized I was missing a "build" folder so I made one within the "andair-master" folder. Then I put my "src" and "public" folders inside the "build" folder and tried running "npm run deploy". Still not working. I notice that my github is missing a gh-pages branch. I am not sure how to make a gh-pages branch or why "npm run deploy" is not working. If anyone could tell me if I'm missing a step, that would be greatly apprecitated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few missing dependencies in your `create-react-app` project. This probably happened because you tried to export the project from codesandbox (I'm not sure though)

You have to fix those first.

**Dependency 1** (`react-scripts`):

```
npm install react-scripts --save-dev
```

**Dependency 2** (`node-sass` because you are using `scss` in your project)

```
npm install node-sass --save
```

**Dependency 3** (`gh-pages`)

```
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
```

After the above steps are completed, verify your package.json to match below structure

```
{
  "name": "and-air",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "homepage": "https://develijahlee.github.io/andair/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Now you can run the **deploy** script

```
npm run deploy
```

After this step, verify that a new branch created with name `gh-pages`

[image]

Click on the **settings** tab in github

[image]

Scroll down to the **GitHub Pages** section and switch your branch to `gh-pages` branch.

[image]

You should get a success message when the page is live.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I finally got a "Compiled successfully" message after downloading the missing dependencies. I finally got a "gh-pages" branch after logging into my github account via git bash but I am getting a 404 error. I tried looking at your Forked repo and everything seems similar to mine. My Github pages source is "gh-pages" so I'm not sure why I am getting this 404 error. Would greatly appreciate it if you had any advice on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: Tried this URL? https://develijahlee.github.io/andair/. I can see the deployed app :)

Comment: Ah I see it now, guess it was just loading. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Ok, You are good to go :) . I'm deleting my sample repo and gh page

Comment: Thank you again, but I was wondering how you got the images to show? I used the Chrome developer tools to change the "../img" paths to "./img" which seems to resolve the issue. I went to andair/src/App.js to change the image paths from two dots to one and committed the file to github, but the changes are not yet showing.

Comment: Run npm run deploy again. You are pushing changes to master but the actual code is in gh-pages  branch. That should be it

Comment: @NithinThampi can we create a build from within codesandbox itself?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what deploy script in your code:

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

Which is means gh-pages tool use build directory to make it deploy, so you need two things in order to make it work

- Create a build folder properly with the following command:

```
npm run build
```

- now install gh-pages tool for your add locally:

```
npm i gh-pages
```

Now you can run deploy command, and it'll work.
I hope this can be helpful to you.